# How to pass variable from php to javascript, as attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to pass a variable from php to HTML as "attribute" so that javascript (jQuery) could access that.

```
$variable = addslashes(   this is the text, coming from database, which can contain '' ' ' ' ' or "" " " " "" " or even <br><hr> tags   );
```

HTML:

```
<img id="clickMe" titleAttr="<?php echo $variable; ?>" />
```

JS:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    alert ($(this).attr('titleAttr'));
});
```

now Firefox say its a bad HTML code, and `alert()` shows the text until the first ' signal (the rest is cut off)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `htmlspecialchars` not `addslashes`.

There is almost always a better escaping mechanism than `addslashes` for any situation, and when there isn't, `addslashes` is rarely sufficient so you need to write one.

`addslashes` is particularly poor for inserting data into HTML since `\` is not an escape character in HTML.

Comment: "since \ is not an escape character in HTML." that was the key